# Get category URL knowing it's id

Tags: categories, permalinks

I have id of WP category on external resource.
I know that if I have id of post I can create url like

> http://example.com/?p={post_id}

But what if I know id of category? How can I generate link to it?
Category permalinks look like

> http://example.com/category/{category_slug}/

and I need to use something like

> http://example.com/category/?cat_id={category_id}/

Comment: Set Permalinks to Plain and visit a category to see for yourself.

Comment: **Custom taxonomy:** you can do `?taxonomy_key=a-term-slug` e.g. `?sport_category=some-ball-game` , I had no luck of finding a way with just term_id ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have category ID you can create link to category like below :

```
<a href="/index.php?cat=7">Category Title</a>
```

For more details read from this link :

https://codex.wordpress.org/Linking_Posts_Pages_and_Categories

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use [get_term_link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/):

```
print get_term_link( $category_id, $taxonomy );
```

Comment: I cannot use WP functions because I generating URLs on external resource

Comment: You could use `?category_name=$slug` and let WP do a redirect to the actual permalink for you, if that's OK, or does it have to rely on the ID?

Comment: I don't have slug I have only list with ids of categories. If I had slug i could generate url http://example.com/category/$slug/ but it is not my case

Answer (score 1):

If you have the category id then you can easily get the category URL using the below code.

```
get_category_link( $category_id );
```

***Example:***

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_category_link( $category_id) ); ?>"  class="view_more_button">View More</a>
```